# How can eyeglasses not fall in basketball?

Tags: tropes

In anime basketball such as [Slam Dunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_Dunk_%28manga%29), [Dear Boys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_Boys#Characters) and [Kuroko's Basketball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroko_no_basket), most of the characters with eyeglasses, play basketball without having their eyeglasses fall or broken during the game. How can this happen?

Comment: Magic. Or anime ignoring physics.

Comment: Or maybe their eyeglasses are already part of their body.

Comment: As phrased, I don't think this question is constructive. For one, there are pro basketball players who wear glasses, and if we looked hard enough we could probably find examples of basketball anime/manga where a character's glasses do break. Furthermore, this trope is present in many media, not just anime and maga. I doubt very much that there is a general explanation for all cases beyond what kuwaly posted above. If you specialize it to a particular character, that question might be more answerable.

Comment: Most of the characters in anime basketball who wears eyeglasses, play without having their eyeglasses falling or broken. I'm asking for most of them. If there are characters who had their eyeglasses broken, then they just can include that in their answer.

Comment: I have glasses and I play basketball, cross train, etc without it falling. Like StarPilot said, all you need are glasses with curved edges and you're good to go. It helps that the lens I use are plastic and the frames are either titanium or plastic (there are a lot of sports glasses, although expensive, that are bendable so even if they fly off, they won't break easily).

That said, I think that this question is not answerable because what answer do you expect from a 'how' question? People can just state their own experiences and it'll be subjective. There's no straight answer for this IMHO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In real life, people that wear glasses often wear "sports bands" when they are concerned about their glasses flying away during athletic events. However, well fit glasses don't need any additional enhancements as long as the athlete isn't performing many rolls. Simple jumps are not enough to cause well fitting glasses to fall or fly away in this case.

In addition to that, some glasses have highly curved end pieces to help secure glasses on the wearer. These end pieces wrap further around the ears than simple straight pieces, and this helps keep the glasses secure.